# SQL Inner join puzzle

Tags: sql

I'm listing topics in my forum, using the following SQL;

```
select t.* , lp.latestpost, lp.lpname
from forum_topics as t 
inner join ( 
    select p.topic, max(p.date) as latestpost, p.author_name as lpname
    from forum_replies p 
    group by p.topic
) lp on lp.topic = t.id
order by lp.latestpost desc
LIMIT 20
```

The problem is its never giving me the correct name of the topics last poster (lpname). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an arbitrary value for the last name, because you are using a MySQL extension.  As a general rule, the columns in the `select` part of an aggregation should be in aggregation functions or in the `group by` clause.  In your case, `p.author_name` is neither.

You can fix this using a hack involving `group_concat()` and `substring_index()`:

```
select t.* , lp.latestpost, lp.lpname
from forum_topics as t inner join
     (select p.topic, max(p.date) as latestpost,
             substring_index(group_concat(p.author_name order by p.date desc separator '|'
                                         ), '|', 1) as as lpname
      from forum_replies p 
      group by p.topic
     ) lp
     on lp.topic = t.id
order by lp.latestpost desc
LIMIT 20;
```